# Create dynamic Python list with N elements

Tags: python, list

Is there a dynamic way (without resorting to a loop or using the fixed `[]`) of creating a Python list with `N` elements?

The elements can be anything e.g. strings, numbers, characters, etc. For example if `N = 6`, how can I dynamically create a list that has 6 string elements `"abc"`?

```
["abc", "abc", "abc", "abc", "abc","abc"]
```

This should be dynamic for different values of `N` and the list elements.

Comment: `['abc' for _ in range(6)]`?

Comment: Simple `["abc"] * N`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pythonic way to do this is:

```
["abc"]*6
```

As jonsharpe commented, if you elements are mutable, this will create elements with the same reference. To create a new object in each case, you could do

```
[[] for _ in range(6)]
```

Comment: Well done for finding enough characters to make a legal answer

Comment: This will cause an issue if the value is mutable

Comment: In OPs case it is not, so I think it is cleaner.

Comment: Yes, but they specifically state *"The elements can be anything"* (although their examples are all immutable, it's worth at least *mentioning* the possible gotcha).

Comment: @jonrsharpe Indeed. I've updated my answer.